# Как включить модуль в проект?

Tags: android

Есть вот такая библиотека

https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

В проекте 2 модуля один `Sample` и второй `ucop` в котором собственно и сидит вся логика которая используется в модуле `Sample`

Так вот проблема в том, что если я копирую модуль `ucop` в свой проект и добавляю

в своем модуле градле  такое

```
dependencies {
...
 implementation project(':ucrop')
....
}
```

Потом в `settings.gradle` `include ':ucrop', ':app'`

Вроде бы больше ничего не нужно , чтоб сказать проекту , что мне нужно использовать этот модуль

Пытаюсь скомпилировать и получаю вот такую ошибку

> Resolving this BuildableArtifact can only done during task execution.
>
> The module 'ucrop' is an Android project without build variants, and cannot be built.
>   Please fix the module's configuration in the build.gradle file and sync the project again.

Посмотрел на стаке, что это может быть и ничего мне не помогло....

Почему проект не принимает этот модуль?